# How to poll the sqs in camel using the quartz2 cron

Tags: java, cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, amazon-sqs

I have to poll the AWS queue in configured time. So, I preferred to use the quartz2 cron configuration. Please see below for code snippet..

```
from("quartz2://instructor?cron=0 0/30 * * * ?")
.routeId("instruction route").log("after 30 min delay")
.from(getQueueUrl())
.bean(rocessor, "process(*)").end();
```

But here the route is started to poll the queue when my application starts. Please suggest / advise me....

Answer (score 3):

The aws-sqs component has support for using quartz2 as its scheduler, see details at: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html and this blog: http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/08/apache-camel-212-even-easier-cron.html

Comment: my question is how to use quartz2 with polling aws sqs

Comment: and yes you can do that as its built-in - read those links again

Comment: really I do not find anything to config schedule to poll message from sqs in quartz2 ....